# How to get key values in MultiMap Blackberry

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to get key values in MultiMap Blackberry while parsing XML

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the apidocs for MultiMap? There's a keys() method that returns an enumeration.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/MultiMap.html